un-breakable tcolorbox inside a tcolorbox
I am trying to write a environment that resembles a theater play. As stated in here, it is not possible to include a breakable tcolorbox inside another tcolorbox, so I decided to separate every dialogue into a sequence of 3 tcolorboxes: DIA, DIAin and PAR. Here is the code:
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{courierten}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{calc}

% PAGE DIMENSIONS %
\setlength{\paperheight}{11in}
\setlength{\paperwidth}{8.5in}
\renewcommand*{\baselinestretch}{0.9}
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}

\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0.5in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.5in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.5in}
\setlength{\headsep}{0.38in}
\setlength{\topskip}{0in}

\setlength{\textheight}{8.9in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.0in}

\newlength{\parentab}
\setlength{\parentab}{1.25in}
\newlength{\parenwidth}
\setlength{\parenwidth}{2.75in}
\newlength{\widthgutter}
\setlength{\widthgutter}{0.1in}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{\widthgutter}

% SETUP
\renewcommand*{\familydefault}{\ttdefault}
\newlength{\dialnametab}
\setlength{\dialnametab}{2.5in}

% NUMBERING
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\renewcommand{\thepage}{I-1-\arabic{page}}% Number page

\begin{document}
% SETUP FONT
    \fontsize{12.3pt}{15.2pt}\selectfont

% tcolorBOXES
    \tcbsetforeverylayer{
        size=minimal,
        halign=flush left,
        breakable,
        interior hidden,
        frame hidden,
        coltitle=black,
        nobeforeafter
    }

% 1) NORMAL DIALOGUE:
    \newtcolorbox{DIA}[2][]{ %LISTO
        before skip=\baselineskip, % Space after last item, before box
        top=2mm, % Space between title and text in box
        title=\hspace{\dialnametab}\parbox{6.0in-\dialnametab}{#2},
        width=6.0in, % F_ put txt_wdth here
        title after break={\color{black} \hspace{\dialnametab}\parbox{6.0in-\dialnametab}{#2 \qquad(Cont.)}\\[-4.7mm] },
        enhanced,
        #1
    }

% 2) In DIALOGUE:
    \newtcolorbox{DIAin}[2][]{ %LISTO
        title={},
        before skip=-1.3mm,
        top=0mm,
        title after break={\color{black} \vspace{-.5pt} \hspace{\dialnametab}\parbox{6.0in - \dialnametab}{#2 \qquad(Cont.)}\\[-2.8mm]},
        enhanced,
        #1
    }

% 3) STAGE DIRECTION: (PAR)
    \newtcolorbox{PAR}[2][]{ %LISTO
        title={},
        top=.7mm, % Space between title and text in box
        left=\parentab,
        width=\parenwidth+\parentab,
        after=\\,
        after skip=0.8mm,
        title after break={\color{black} \hspace{-\parentab+\dialnametab}\parbox{6.0in-\dialnametab}{#2 \qquad(Cont.)} \\[-3mm]},
        enhanced,
        #1
    }

%% DIALOGUE 1 %%
\begin{DIA}{CESAR}
    Aliquam volutpat est vel massa. Sed dolor
\end{DIA}
\begin{PAR}{CESAR}
    (\lipsum[66] \lipsum[75] Aliquam
    volutpat est vel massa. Integer
    pretium semper justo.
    Proin risus. Nullam id
    quam. Nam neque. Aliquam
    volutpat est vel massa. Integer
    pretium semper justo.
    Proin risus.)
\end{PAR}

%% DIALOGUE 2 %%
\begin{DIA}{OTHELLO}
    Aliquam volutpat est vel massa.
    Integer pretium semper
\end{DIA}
\begin{PAR}{OTHELLO}
    (Aliquam volutpat est vel massa. Integer
    pretium semper justo.
    Proin risus.Aliquam
    volutpat est vel massa. Integer
    pretium semper justo mo.)
\end{PAR}
\begin{DIAin}{OTHELLO}
    Integer semper justo.
    Proin risus. Nullam id
    quam. Nam. Proin risus. Nullam id
    quam. Nam neque. Aliquam
    volutpat est vel massa. Integer
    pretium semper justo.
\end{DIAin}
\begin{PAR}{OTHELLO}
    (OTHELLO jumps Proin risus. Nullam id
    quam. Nam neque. Aliquam
    volutpat est vel massa. Integer
    pretium semper justo.)
\end{PAR}
%
\end{document}

You can keep adding text to any tcolorbox (DiA, DIAin, PAR) and if there is no more space left in the page, it will break the current page and continue on the next one with the correct character title: CESAR   (Cont.)
UNFORTUNATELY in the example that I am showing, OTHELLO starts a new dialogue close to the end of the first page and there is one tcolorbox (PAR) in his dialogue that by chance ends exactly when there is no more space left on the page for the next environment (DIAin) to start.
First Page:

Because there is no break of a tcolorbox, the top of the Second page has no title:

The Second page should be:

It is unlikely that a tcolorbox inside a dialogue ends exactly at the end of a page, but in the chance it happens, I will have to correct it manually.
Any thoughts?

Welcome to TeX.SE! Did you get error messages or warnings? Which one?

Hi. No errors, no warnings.

It would be maybe simpler to use only the DIA tcolorbox and change inside the margins for the DIAin and PAR content (see How can I change the margins for only part of the text?).

Thanks jlab. changepage package did the trick. I tried minipage, parbox and other environments but all jumped to the next page carrying the whole text with them. adjustwidth environment works great inside tcolorbox

parbox and minipage create boxes, they don't break at page end. adjustwidth use a list behind.

I’m voting to close this question because it was solved in comments.
